# When were the foundations of vector calculus laid?

Tags: calculus, electromagnetism, heaviside

Upon some browsing I find from many online sources that vector calculus was created in the time of late 19th century by Gibbs and Heaviside, but Gauss, Green, Stokes, etc., who lived much before that, have obviously contributed to deep and fundamental theorems of vector calculus. So what exactly transpired, and what do we exactly mean when we say that Heaviside and Gibbs created vector calculus? Was it just a notational simplification and unification of many scattered ideas, or is it something else?

Comment: Gauss, Green and Stokes (as well as Euler, Lagrange, Liouville, Maxwell and others) worked with expressions in multiple variables without assembling them into vectors and manipulating those according to systematic rules. Later, after Hamilton's quaternions provided the pattern, what they did was translated into a new language by Gibbs, Heaviside and others. It was more than just notational simplification and unification, it was a discovery and development of a new structure behind the language that happened to be able to accomplish that.

Comment: @Conifold Quaternions provided the pattern? Did Hamilton manipulate them as vectors, rather than with i, j, k symbols?

Comment: @Frank He treated them as single gadgets and had algebraic rules for operations on them, that was the pattern. Another precursor was Grassman with his exterior algebra, but his *Ausdehnungslehre* was so obscurely written that its ideas did not spread much before vector calculus was already established. So Hamilton was the primary influence.

Comment: @Conifold Hmmm. The concept of vector space is essentially about linearity. If Hamilton had algebraic rules related to the symbols i,j,k, he might have missed the idea of linearity? I guess he had additions of quaternions, but operations on i,j,k would be on top of the linear vector space structure. Did Hamilton recognize he had objects that behaved like modern vectors in terms of linearity?

Comment: @Frank Quaternions are linear combinations of 1,i,j,k and linear operations, addition and multiplication by real numbers, are among the operations on them. Abstractions like vector spaces and linear structure are a later development than use of 2D and 3D vectors and vector calculus.

Comment: @Conifold Just pointing out that things such i^2 = -1 are not part of the modern axioms for a vector space which focuses on vector addition and vector multiplication by a scalar from the base field. In that sense, relations such as i^2 = -1 are added structure on top of the vector space structure.

Comment: [Similar post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/how-were-vector-quantities-developed).

Comment: One of the foundations is clearly in "parallelogram rules", with a long history of use for combining and resolving things like motions and velocities, and later, forces. Newton's earliest draft [_De motu_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_motu_corporum_in_gyrum) gives a parallelogram rule as if it already had something near to axiomatic status.